# How can i get the illumination invariant NIR(Near Infrared) face image in both of outdoor and indoor?

Tags: image-processing, camera, face-recognition, infrared

I am developing the face recognition device.
It uses ov7740 camera module, optical filter passing 850 nm and NIR LEDs.
The images captured in indoor and outdoor are greatly differ due to sunlight.
for example, pupils got white in indoor, but not in outdoor.
Someone said that image in indoor can be retrieved from image in outdoor by differential operation.
So, I got two images in outdoor by turning on and off NIR LEDs, then got a differential image.
But that was very dark lit, so I doubted differential operation was right to retrieve the image in indoor.
Even if, it's right method, NIR component in sunlight to be subtracted would be change due to sunlight direction and object(Face) position.
How can i get the illumination invariant NIR face image in both of outdoor and indoor?
Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: No one has experience or knowledge about this?

Comment: I have to solve this problem urgently.
Please guide me.
Thanks in advance, again.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are some light normalization algorithms out there. My personal favourite is

> Tan & Triggs Illumination Normalization

Here is a small presentation on Tan&Triggs, if you want to take a look at it.
[**slides**](http://www.scribd.com/doc/201718375/Tan-and-Triggs-Illumination-normalization#scribd)

It basically does gamma correction followed by Difference of Gaussian Filter and then contrast equalization.

I have applied it to gray scale images of faces and the result is really good.

If you want to try it out, you can find the code here- [**code**](https://github.com/bytefish/opencv/blob/master/misc/tan_triggs.cpp)

It is quite easy and fast to implement.

I am not sure how good will it work on Infra-red images, but its worth the try.

Cheers and best of luck.

Comment: It seems to be flatten image with lines, so loss the 3 dimensional curvature pattern information.